# TypeScript: Array type in namespace/module

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have this code in a namespace:

```js
    const conj_method = Symbol("conj_method");
    const toSeq_method = Symbol("toSeq_method");

    export interface Array<T> extends IConjable<T>, ISeqable<T> {}

    Array.prototype[conj_method] = function<X>(x: X) {
        this.push(x);
        return this;
    };

    Array.prototype[toSeq_method] = function() {
        return new ArraySeq(this, 0);
    };
```

For some reason this gives me the error:

```
src/seq2.ts:497:21 - error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

497     Array.prototype[conj_method] = function<X>(x: X) {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~

src/seq2.ts:502:21 - error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

502     Array.prototype[toSeq_method] = function() {
```

Several other uses of `particularArray[pointer]` are also erroring for me with similar:

```
src/seq2.ts:430:40 - error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Array<X>'.

430         isEq && tl && ptr < this.array.length;
                                           ~~~~~~

src/seq2.ts:433:23 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Array<X>' has no index signature.

433         isEq = hd === this.array[ptr];
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Not wrapping this code in a namespace resolves these errors.

Answer (score 2):

Augmentations to `Array` must always be in the global scope. When you declare `export interface Array<T> extends IConjable<T>, ISeqable<T> {}` in a namespace, you are not augmenting array, you are creating a new interface called `Array`. The value `Array` (representing the global `Array` constructor will still point to the not augmented global array.

You can place the code in a `namespace` but the augmentation will need to be top level:

```
interface Array<T> extends X.IConjable<T>, X.ISeqable<T> { }
namespace X {
    const conj_method = Symbol("conj_method");
    const toSeq_method = Symbol("toSeq_method");

    export interface IConjable<T> { [conj_method](x: T): this }
    export interface ISeqable<T> { [toSeq_method](x: T): this }

    Array.prototype[conj_method] = function <X>(x: X) {
        this.push(x);
        return this;
    };

    Array.prototype[toSeq_method] = function () {
        return new ArraySeq(this, 0);
    };
}
```

The above version is for script files, that is not modules (ie the file has no top level `export` or `import`) for augmentation to work in a module you need to put the `Array` augmentation in global:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> extends X.IConjable<T>, X.ISeqable<T> { }    
}
```